# How would I write the following css into valid sass, scss?

Tags: css, sass

I have the following css which I want to convert into valid scss sass:

```
        .my-class>li.active>a,
        .my-class>li.active>a:hover,
        .my-class>li.active>a:focus {
           color: #555;
           background-color: #fff;
        }
```

I tried as per below, but it did not give me the exact results:

```
  .myclass {
     .li {
        &.active {
           color: #555;
           background-color: #fff;
           &:hover, &:focus {
              color: #555;
              background-color: #fff;
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: What *did* it give you?

Comment: So what's the benefit of using sass here if it requires more lines than if you  just use vanilla css?

Comment: Use a tool like [**SassMeister**](http://sassmeister.com/) to test code.

Comment: Vanilla CSS is *already* valid SCSS.

Comment: sass is the project styling solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in this way:

```
 .myclass {
     > li.active {
        > a, > a:hover, > a:focus {
            color: #555;
            background-color: #fff;              
        }
     }
  }
```

The resulting output (tested on [sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/)) is

```
.myclass > li.active > a,
.myclass > li.active > a:hover, 
.myclass > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `.myclass` separated from `> li.active` even though there are no rules for just `.myclass`?

Comment: I kept them separated so the user can see how to chain direct children with `>`. Anyway I have already merged `li` with `.active`